# Как из базы данных вывести записи в разные блоки в WinForm?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Как можно вывести данные по определенному контрагенту записи о его заключенных договорах? Нужно чтобы были отдельные блоки, где про каждый договор прописано было. Я  знаю как можно вывести в `DataGridView`, но как можно сделать так, я не знаю.

В Sql я придумал запрос:

```
SELECT Surname, Name, Patronymic, Contract, data_reg, Name_product
FROM Contragent
INNER JOIN Contract on Contragent.ID=Contract.Contragent_id
Inner join product on Contract.product_id=product.ID
Where Contragent.ID=287
```

Вот что-то типо этого, можно ли как-то сделать в WinForms?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу_

Comment: С чем именно у вас проблема: с получением данных из БД (sql-запрос вы составили, значит можете)? с проектированием GUI? с привязкой полученных данных к GUI? Не задавайте несколько вопросов в одной теме; создайте несколько разных тем с конкретным вопросом. И всегда показывайте свою попытку решения.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, я не понимаю как можно вывести информацию в разные блоки, а насчет попытки решения не могу даже придумать что-то, как это можно сделать, я привык просто вывод делать через таблицу, а тут растерялся

Comment: Если вы не знаете, как вывести информацию, то так и задайте вопрос: "Как вывести информацию". Зачем вы вывалили на нас лишние сведения про контрагентов, договора, sql-запрос... Создайте новую тему с правильно сформулированным вопросом.

Comment: Как успехи? Поделитесь.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте Panel, разместите элементы, возьмите код дизайнера и сделайте из него в цикле генерацию панелей по нажатию на кнопку, подставляя нужные данные в Label'ы.
Если нужен клик с дальнейшими обработчиками то при генерации к каждой панели добавить:

```
panel.Click += (s,a) =>
{
  do_something();
};
```

Потом добавляйте эти панели на какую-нибудь другую панель с настроенным скролом.
Я так 10 лет назад делал, работало на ура.
На каждой панели и картинки и кнопки были, сейчас на полном серьёзе такое делать постыдно, и есть куда более цивилизованные способы, но чтобы хоть как-то по-быстрому решить задачу - неплохой вариант.

Comment: Ход мысли правильный. Только лучше вместо панели взять `UserControl`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а вроде UserControl же используется в WPF? я его не увидел в WinForms

Comment: [UserControl](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.usercontrol?view=net-5.0)